# Using let inside ->> macro

Tags: clojure

I have started learning clojure. I am stuck at using let inside `->>` macro

The code is :

```
 (defn make-summary [wordStr]
                                        ;// split string into words
  (let [words (clojure.string/split wordStr #"[\[\]\(\),.\s+]") 
                                        ;// convert words to lowercase.
        lowerCaseWords (map clojure.string/lower-case words)]
                                        ;// remove stop words
    (->> (remove-stop-words lowerCaseWords)           
                                        ;// count the frequency of words  
        ;// ---------- HERE IS THE PROBLEM ------------------------------ 
        (let [totalWords (count )]  ;// <--- HOW TO MAKE MACRO PUT THE THING HERE ???
          (count-frequency)
                                        ;// sort on the basis of frequency
          (sort #(> (get %1 1) (get %2 1)))
                                        ;// find the keywords

        )
        )))
```

I am stuck at the second `let` inside the defn function.

How can i code it ?

Comment: You can't do that. ->> inserts the argument as the last item of the form. It won't get inside a form and insert something in an arbitrary place. Why do you need the second let anyway, and where would you use totalWords?

Comment: As an aside, you may want to use `frequencies`.

Comment: if you really want to use something like let in a ->> or need the argument in different positions, then you could use as->

Comment: @kima can u explain more.. This is what i am looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your original code with the as-> threading macro added in clojure 1.5
instead of inserting its argument to the first (->) or to the last (->>) position of each form, it lets you specify the position:

```
(as-> [1 2 3] x
     (conj x 4)
     (map inc x)) ;=> '(2 3 4 5)
```

I think, the advice is to use -> or ->> when you can and only fall back to as-> if this is not easily done. The summarise function by @Thumbnail is a nice example of the readability you get with ->>.

You can think of as-> as a convenient shorthand for the following code:

```
(let [x [1 2 3]
      x (conj x 4)
      x (map inc x)] x)
```

Here is the relevant part of your code written with as->:

```
(as-> (remove-stop-words lowerCaseWords) x
      (let [totalWords (count x)] .....
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @DiegoBasch's advice ...

If you're looking for

- the words in decreasing order of frequency of use
- eliminating stop words and
- exploiting the `->>` macro

then the following might suit:

```
(defn summarise [text stop-words]
  (->> text
       (re-seq #"[a-zA-Z]+")
       (map clojure.string/lower-case)
       (remove stop-words)
       frequencies
       (sort-by (comp - val))
       (map key)))
```

For examples

```
(summarise "Mary had a HUGE a lamb" #{})
("a" "mary" "had" "huge" "lamb")

(summarise "Mary had a HUGE a lamb" #{"huge"})
("a" "mary" "had" "lamb")
```

Notes

- The function detects words as sequences of letters instead of
  detecting specific separator characters. You can reverse this change
  if you prefer.
- I'd be inclined to make sure that the stop words too are lower case:
  use `(set (map clojure.string/lower-case stop-words))` instead of
  `stop-words` in the `remove`. Otherwise  stop words with upper case
  letters will be ineffective.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it do not answer my question. You have told a lot of good things.. but the problem is with using let inside ->> .. context of the should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have `->>` insert the argument at any place other than last item of the form. But this can be used in a trick to make it happen :

```
(defn make-summary [wordStr]
                                        ;// split string into words

  (let [words (clojure.string/split wordStr #"[\[\]\(\),.\s+]") 
                                        ;// convert words to lowercase.
        lowerCaseWords (map clojure.string/lower-case words)]
                                        ;// remove stop words
    (->> (remove-stop-words lowerCaseWords)           
                                        ;// count the frequency of words  

    (fn [LCW] (let [totalWords (count LCW)]  ;// <--- HOW TO MAKE MACRO PUT THE THING HERE ???
          (count-frequency)
                                        ;// sort on the basis of frequency
          (sort #(> (get %1 1) (get %2 1)))
                                        ;// find the keywords

        )
        ))))
```

What i have done is wrapped the things inside the function, and now you can put the argument at any place.